# Have to log in to see answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

You can't see answers on the android app unless you're logged in. There's no indication that you have to log in to see answers.

Comment: Only answers, or anything?

Comment: @gunr2171 only answers.

Comment: Repro'd, looking into it now.

Answer (score 3):

I had generated a bad API filter for the anonymous use case, which was attempting to read logged-in-only data, which caused the call to fail and not bring back anything bad the question. As of the next update (1.0.51) going out in the next few hours, this will be fixed. Thanks!